# Replace any string of over 8 characters beginning with a / with a link?

Tags: jquery, regex

How do I use jQuery to replace any strings of text beginning with / and over 8 characters (the string of text ends at the first empty space) with a link leading to imugr.com/the string of text here?

For example:

`/sA9xK4D` would be converted to `<a href="imugr.com/sA9xK4D">/sA9xK4D</a>`

`/Pq9xV39x a,#xK2F` would be converted to `<a href="imgur.com/Pq9xV39x">/Pq9xV39x</a> a,#xK2F`

This code is not working; it says undefined is not a function.

```
content = $("body").replace(/(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8})(?=\s)/g, '<a href="http://www.imgur.com$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
$("body").html(content)
```

Comment: I think you need a regex.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this. JavaScript has native regexes.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with that.

Comment: over 8 chars (8 or more). also I added the code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})(?=\s)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Replace by `<a href="industus.com$1">$1</a>`

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fd1AZaAeL4kRBnC_)

Demo on [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/391u8)

---

How to use it in JavaScript (example):

```js
// initial content
var content = document.getElementById("init").innerHTML;

// replace using the "global" flag
// see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
content = content.replace(/(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})(?=\s)/g, '<a href="industus.com$1">$1</a>');

// set replaced content in other div
document.getElementById("replaced").innerHTML = content;
```

Demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNN8r/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to capture the first part into group1 and the next part to group2,

```
^(\/[^\s]*)(.*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nX5gO6)

Comment: How do I use that in jQuery though?

Answer (score 0):

try this example:

```
var re = /\/[\w\d]{8,}/;
var string = "this is my string /aZ2scXo35676";

var link = string.match(re)[0]; // will match "/aZ2scXo35676"

var result = string.replace(re, TEMP.replace(/\[AAA\]/g, link[0]))

// result will equal 'this is my string <a href="industus.com/aZ2scXo35676">/aZ2scXo35676</a>'
```

Comment: The question is what are you trying to achieve with you final a tag? what are you trying to use jquery FOR exactly?

Comment: Side note: `\w` already contains `\d` in it (`\w` is `[0-9A-Za-z_]`, `\d` is `[0-9]`), so `[\w\d]` is a bit redundant and could be simply replaced by `\w`.